# CsvParameterLayout in Log4j2 is inserting NUL character if data starts and ends with {}

Tags: java, json, csv, escaping, log4j2

I am using CsvParameterLayout to generate a CSV file. One of the column is a JSON string. Following is the logger method I am using:

```
logger.info("log:{}",json);
```

Following is the JSON string:

```
{"id":10,"name":"sumit"}
```

And following is the string which is getting printed in CSV output file:

```
 NUL{"id":10,"name":"sumit"}NUL
```

The NUL character is the \x00 character. When I open the file in notepad++, then only this character appears. In notepad it shows as space. This poses a problem in CSV processing module.

If there is some alphabet before {, then the output in CSV is fine. It seems as if log4j is escaping '{' with a NUL character. It is happening if the string starts with {, (, [, ' or ".

Can someone please let me know if I can escape '{' and '"' in code so that log4j does not include NUL character in output?

Comment: Please raise this on the [Log4j 2 issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2). It may be a problem with the commons-csv library that Log4j 2 uses for the CSV layouts.

Comment: This is now fixed in Git master commit f9a5d552a9040c50adcfdd46fc2aeff67281bd76 which will end up in release 2.7. Tracking here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1502